# Linux set date&time via bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to set a fake date via bash script 
I'm using the following commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'myPass' | sudo -s 'date -s "1 NOV 2011 09:00:00"'
```

But I'm getting command error.
What is the right way to do it ?

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` does not read the password from standard input by default, but from the terminal itself, so you cannot pipe your password into `sudo` this way. You need to use the `-S` option to read from standard input.

```
echo "myPass" | sudo -S date -s "1 NOV 2011 09:00:00"
```

(note that you don't need to use the `-s` (lowercase) option; `sudo` can run `date` directly without starting an intervening shell).

Exposing your password like this, however, is a security risk. It would be better to configure `sudo` to allow you (or anyone who is intended to run this script) to run
this particular `date` command without a password.

Answer (score -2):

For sudo, the first parameter without a dash is the command to execute, the following parameters are the arguments to give to that command. If you wrap the command and its arguments together in quotes (e.g. `"echo foo"`), then sudo tries to execute the command "echo foo" instead of the command "echo" with parameter "foo". Hence, you need to omit the outermost quotes:

```
sudo date -s "1 NOV 2011 09:00:00"
```

Comment: The `-s` option to `sudo` starts a shell, and the command argument is passed to the shell for execution.